# List of associated resources in React Admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a REST API that lets you access associated resources like this:

- `GET /samples` lists all samples
- `GET /samples/1` describes sample 1 in detail
- `GET /samples/1/data` lists all data belonging to sample 1

I'm trying to hook this up with [`react-admin`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Readme.html), where I have the following `<Admin>` component:

```html
<Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="samples" list={SampleList} show={SampleShow} edit={SampleEdit}/>
</Admin>
```

So, I now want to add a list component for `data`, but I *do not* want the user to be able to list all data. I just want the user to be able to see all data associated with a sample: a page representing the `GET /samples/1/data` URL.

As a consequence, I don't want `data` appearing as a resource on the sidebar/front page. I just want to have a `SampleList` and `SampleShow` components to be able to link to a list of associated data. How can I do this with `react-admin`?

Comment: You can create your menu with only the required resources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57404053/react-admin-create-a-custom-page-which-can-be-accessed-from-menu-sidebar/57405004#57405004

Comment: True, but that doesn't solve the issue of wanting to have a page that only shows the data attached to a single sample.Which the regular List component wouldn't do.

Comment: The most similar solution in react-admin is to create a separate 'data' resource and access it through reference input / field.

Comment: But will the data resource only show data items for my selected sample? If so, that's the solution I'm looking for

Comment: Possibly, but the URL format will be different: https://marmelab.com/react-admin//Fields.html#referencefield

Comment: No, `ReferenceField` doesn't do it. It "fetches a single referenced record, and displays one field of this record". I want to display multiple references records, and ideally on their own page.